# IOS 12 decides the keyboard type even if I change it by code

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a login screen that has two functionalities: sign up and login with the same text boxes. Depending on the selected action (button) it should works different:

```
if action == "SIGN_UP" {

    txtMail.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.emailAddress
}
else{

    txtMail.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.default
}

txtMail.reloadInputViews()
```

The problem is that the text box keeps in memory the first keyboard that was selected and does not change it if I select the other option. Ex:

I select "Sign Up" option, then I can see the suggestions for emails in the keyboard when I select the text box (That is ok).
Then I return back and select "Login" option, then it still shows the same suggestions.

Now the worst part: restart the app, First I select "Login" option: The system shows the passwords button (That is ok), but if I go back and clic on "Sign Up" the system keeps that suggestion (passwords button) even if I change it by code to `UIKeyboardType.emailAddress`.

Ive seen something related to heuristics in the page of Apple but not the solution: [About the Password AutoFill workflow](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow)

Any suggestions?

Comment: When are you setting the keyboardType?

Comment: Each time that I want to change the mode, there are two buttons "Sign Up" and "Login", each one calls the same method when I clic them with a parameter that identifies the button that fired the event. In that method I have the code that I showed in the post.

Comment: Are you resigning the first responder before  changing keyboard type? I.e. Hide the keyboard, change type, then present it again?

Comment: Exactly, I have to say that everything is in the same storyboard: I change the visibility of the text box with `txtMail.isHidden = true` and call methods `txtMail.resignFirstResponder()` and `self.view.endEditing(true)` in the button "Back". Then I want to show the text field again with the new attribute changing the keyboard type but it does not work (keeps the same keyboard type that was selected the first time).  :|

Answer (score 0):

Try this  after your if statement

```
    view.endEditing(true)
    txtMail.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: I have already tried that, but didn't work. It seems like an internal feature on iOS/swift :|